# Exporting JPEG images to PDF losslessly (without modifying them)

Tags: export, pdf-format

I have several JPG images each representing one page of document. I want to export them to PDF file but without re-encoding them. I am able to do it, but images are always modified by *Mathematica*.

EDIT: I was doing something wrong. *Mathematica* exports JPEG images to PDF without modifying them, i.e. the exported images are identical pixel by pixel with original ones. Sorry for any inconvenience. And thanks Alexey Popkov for his patience with me.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not possible with Mathematica. Once you import a JPEG, Mathematica forgets what compressed format it was in. It's just pixel data. On re-export it will be re-encoded. However, I believe Mathematica does not use JPEG compression on images when writing PDFs. Thus I do not think you will *lose* data, but you *will* lose the JPEG compression.

Comment: I would recommend **imagemagick** command line tools.

Comment: Or Acrobat... combining pages is one of the things it does well.

Comment: @bills But are you sure that Acrobat doesn't recompress JPEG? AFAIK it does...

Comment: @Szabolcs: Definitely you will lose data. I compered pixels from original JPG and pixels of the same image exported from PDF and they were different. So it is even worse if it does not use compression and anyway it changes pixels data.

Comment: @azerbajdzan The difference in pixel data you observe may be a consequence of applying a *color profile* by the PDF renderer/reader you used. Which PDF reader you used for exporting? For example, Acrobat automatically applies a color profile without asking the user...

Comment: @Alexey Popkov: I used Adobe Acrobat Reader but I do not think it is dependent on reader because I used right click on image and then "copy image" into clipboard. So I did not compare pixel as it appears inside reader but pixel after extracting it from PDF.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov: And I know it is possible to export JPEG into PDF without any modification of pixels. Using LaTeX for example. Doing so if you compare pixels of original JPEG with pixels of image copied from PDF then they are identical.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I just performed a checkup with `ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]`: I used `Export` for exporting it to PDF, then opened the PDF in Acrobat 11.0.11.18 where I selected the image by clicking on it and then used "Copy Image" right-click menu item. Then I pasted it in *Mathematica* and compared `ImageData` of it with the original. They are *exactly* equal! But when I used `Import` on this PDF file I obtained an image with altered colors... So `Export` works correctly, but `Import` seems to be broken in some way.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Also, it is important how do you create PDF from *Mathematica*? Using the "Save Selection As..." or "Save As..." menu item you can get another result than using `Export`. The latter proved to be the most reliable.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov: Yes it works with a single image, but try to export two JPEGs to PDF that each image is on its own page.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Please provide the code you used for exporting (include it in the question).

Comment: @Alexey Popkov: Oh, no. I was doing something wrong. I restarted mathematica and rewrite the whole code and it works now as it should.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I was a bit wrong too: actually `Import` doesn't alter pixel values, it just returns a `Graphics` object instead of `Image`, which later is rasterized with lower resolution producing other pixel values. With `"Images"` as second argument of `Import` I obtained exactly the same pixel values.